# Extract multiple but specific values from a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot specific values from a dataframe when I plot it regularly it gives me [This Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LzWm.jpg) but the plot I want is [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOGE3.jpg); However I can't seem to be able to find the correct syntax to make it. The code I use gives me:

```
Error in Food$Ár[1, 5, 9, 11] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Code:

```
plot(x = Food$Ár[1,5,9,11], y = Food$Yngri.en.67.ára.Fjöldi[1,5,9,11], type = "o")
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible data example. Using `dput` should do it.

Comment: You can subset your column as such: `Food$Ár[c(1,5,9,11)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to subset specific rows, for which you know the row indices by number, `[]` will work.

```
dat <- data.frame(list(
x = sample(c("Apple","Orange","Banana","Chicken","Fish","Tomato"),
         size = 12, replace = T),
y = sample(c("Sweet","Savory","Spicy","Salty"),
         size = 12, replace = T)))

head(dat)
        x      y
1  Orange Savory
2    Fish  Salty
3 Chicken  Spicy
4   Apple  Spicy
5  Banana  Sweet
6 Chicken  Salty

#To select rows 1, 5, 9, and 11:
dat[c(1,5,9,11), ]
         x      y
1   Orange Savory
5   Banana  Sweet
9  Chicken  Spicy
11  Orange Savory
```